# Find correleation between values and degrees

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, nonlinear-system, angle

I have an arc that starts at $252$ degrees and ends at $288$ degrees, I would like to assign non - linear values on it with this ratio:

$1 - 180$ degrees.
$5 - 135$ degrees.
$10 - 90$ degrees.
$30 - 45$ degrees.
$50 - 0$ degrees.

I would like to find some sort of formula that will enable me to locate any given value on the arc, for example: where exactly on the arc will i find $42$? or $7.89?$ here is an illustration of said arc:
 [image]

Comment: For me, the 30 is much closer to the 50 than to the 10.

Comment: @wythagoras The scale isn't quite logarithmic either.

Comment: When you say *non-linear* do you mean *piecewise linear*? In other words, do you want the values to progress linearly within the different zones but possibly at different rates? And if not, then you need to decide on what other conditions you want to impose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can write a formula to map the degree value to your index.  It depends on how smooth you want the function to be at the boundaries.

But a simple way would be just a linear relation between each tick mark (here, $x$ is the angle in degrees and $f(x)$ is your index):

$$f(x) = \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{l l}
     1 + (4/45)(180-x) & 180 \geq x \geq 135 \\
     5 + (5/45)(135-x) & 135 > x \geq 90 \\
     10 + (20/45)(90-x) & 90 > x \geq 0
   \end{array} \right.$$